# Vuforia reinit after deinit in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, virtual-reality

guys.

I got a problem with Vuforia VR and AR transition in unity.

I just want to change scene like this...

3D scene -> VR scene -> 3D scene -> AR scene

I tried to make this order workflow but it is not working.

before I quit VR scene, I used this code.

```
Vuforia.VuforiaUnity.Deinit();
```

or

```
Vuforia.VuforiaRuntime.Instance.Deinit();
```

and

```
Vuforia.VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.enabled = false;
```

because of these code, I can turn off VR Camera and successfully open 3D scene.

(without this code, I can't open 3D scene because VR camera still working!)

however, whenever I open AR scene after 3D scene, there are some errors and AR Camera is not work.

```
Could not create dataset.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Vuforia.ObjectTracker:CreateDataSet()
Vuforia.DatabaseLoadARController:LoadDatasets()
Vuforia.VuforiaARController:StartAfterInitializationCompleted()
Vuforia.VuforiaARController:Start()
System.Delegate:DynamicInvoke(Object[])
Vuforia.DelegateHelper:InvokeDelegate(Delegate, Object[])
Vuforia.DelegateHelper:InvokeWithExceptionHandling(Action)
Vuforia.VuforiaBehaviour:Start()
```

and

```
Failed to set frame format
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Vuforia.CameraDevice:SetFrameFormat(PIXEL_FORMAT, Boolean)
Vuforia.CameraDevice:ForceFrameFormat(PIXEL_FORMAT, Boolean)
Vuforia.CameraDevice:Start()
Vuforia.MixedRealityController:StartCameraAndTrackersIfStopped()
Vuforia.MixedRealityController:SetViewerAR()
Vuforia.MixedRealityController:SetMode(Mode)
TransitionManager:Update() (at Assets/SamplesResources/Scripts/TransitionManager.cs:106)
```

To Sum up, AR camera in AR scene is not working After Deinit() method.

is there anyway to reinit vuforia

or

turn off VR camera without using Deinit() method?

Comment: Did you try to just set the gameObject of the AR/Vr camera of Vuforia to false? (Requires the AR/VR camera of Vuforia to be on a different object than the main camera ofcourse)

Comment: Actually, I just generated and used cameras in each scene. I'm gonna try to do this way and answer to you. Thank you for your advise, derHugo.